# ASP.Net's Gridview Fix Header using JQuery is lost after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

In reference to the tutorial of this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-freeze-ASP.Net-Gridview-header-using-JavaScript.aspx that shows how to fixate a gridview header and add a vertical scrollbar,

After a postback due to action made in the page, the effect using jquery was lost.

here's the jquery

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var GridId = "<%=GridView1.ClientID %>";
    var ScrollHeight = 300;
    window.onload = function () {
        var grid = document.getElementById(GridId);
        var gridWidth = grid.offsetWidth;
        var gridHeight = grid.offsetHeight;
        var headerCellWidths = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.getElementsByTagName("TH").length; i++) {
            headerCellWidths[i] = grid.getElementsByTagName("TH")[i].offsetWidth;
        }
        grid.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        var parentDiv = grid.parentNode;

        var table = document.createElement("table");
        for (i = 0; i < grid.attributes.length; i++) {
            if (grid.attributes[i].specified && grid.attributes[i].name != "id") {
                table.setAttribute(grid.attributes[i].name, grid.attributes[i].value);
            }
        }
        table.style.cssText = grid.style.cssText;
        table.style.width = gridWidth + "px";
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
        table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0]);
        var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("TH");

        var gridRow = grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            var width;
            if (headerCellWidths[i] > gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth) {
                width = headerCellWidths[i];
            }
            else {
                width = gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth;
            }
            cells[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
            gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
        }
        parentDiv.removeChild(grid);

        var dummyHeader = document.createElement("div");
        dummyHeader.appendChild(table);
        parentDiv.appendChild(dummyHeader);
        var scrollableDiv = document.createElement("div");
        if(parseInt(gridHeight) > ScrollHeight){
             gridWidth = parseInt(gridWidth) + 17;
        }
        scrollableDiv.style.cssText = "overflow:auto;height:" + ScrollHeight + "px;width:" + gridWidth + "px";
        scrollableDiv.appendChild(grid);
        parentDiv.appendChild(scrollableDiv);
    }
script>
```

Comment: It's correct... fix header work client side. You have to store the position in a cookie - for example - and then retrieve it when the page is reloaded

Comment: Bad use for a cookie. If you just need to save a value for a round trip, drop a `HiddenField` on the page with `ClientIDMode` set to `Static` and you can access that value from both the code behind and the JS via it's ID